# How to change selector with .not to apply to dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, selector, document

I am new to jQuery and hope someone can help me with this.

I currently use the below snippet which works as intended so far.
However, **I now need to change this so that it can be used for dynamically added elements** and am facing some issues with the `.not` here.

**My current code:**

```
$('.customSelect dd ul li a').not('.disabled, .selectMain').on('click', function(){
    var selectHtml = $(this).html(),
        selectVal = $(this).next('span.selectVal').text();
    $(this).closest('div.divSelect').attr('name', selectVal).find('dt a span.selectActive').html(selectHtml).end().find('dd ul').hide();
});
```

I know that I can write the following but I am not sure how to apply the .not then to this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.customSelect dd ul li a', function(){
    // ...
});
```

Many thanks in advance and sorry for this beginner question,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [:not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$(document).on('click', '.customSelect dd ul li a:not(.disabled, .selectMain)', function() {
    // do something...
});
```

Or alternatively, you can use the `hasClass()` method:

```
$(document).on('click', '.customSelect dd ul li a', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled') || $(this).hasClass('selectMain'))
        return;

    // do something...
});
```

Comment: Awesome, yeah - that's it. Thanks a lot for the quick help - will accept as soon as I can !

Comment: Thanks for the update also - the :not works great for me. :)